# Is the set of decreasing functions from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$ countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to prove the set of decreasing functions from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$ is countable.

I considered a decreasing function, $f$, with a least element, $n$, and let $x$ be the smallest number such that $f(x)=n$.

Is it ok that since $f$ is decreasing that for all $y>x$, $f(y)=f(x)=n$?

By doing so $i$ can then show *non-increasing* functions can be defined by the set $\{f(1),\dotsc,f(x)\}$ and I think I can do the rest.

Comment: How about considering the set of possible largest values? Also, do you mean $f$ non-increasing, or do you want actually decreasing?

Comment: I want f decreasing definitely

Comment: @user116498 There aren't any strictly decreasing functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: But that's not possible; start with $f(1)$, which is the largest value. Then you have only finitely-many choices for the infinite set {$f(2),f(3),....$}

Comment: Oh wait I do mean non increasing!

Comment: So does my original claim stand?

Comment: Let's see: once you define $f(1)$, and you have $f(k)=1$, the rest of the function is all identically $1$. So it depends on those two values.

Comment: Please remember to use the shift key when typing. Please also remember not to use the capslock key when typing.

Comment: Your basic idea is fine but needs a small tweak. If $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ is non-decreasing, let $$m_f=\min\left\{n\in\Bbb N:\forall k\ge n\big(f(k)=f(n)\big)\right\}\;;$$ then $f$ is completely determined by the finite sequence $\langle f(0),\ldots,f(m_f)\rangle$. You can replace the sequence by a [multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset), but you can’t use a plain set, since there may be some repetitions: you can’t assume that the function is strictly decreasing before the constant tail.

Answer (score 10):

Define
$$S_N:=\{f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}\;|\; f \text{ is non-increasing and } f(1)\leq N\}$$
Then, your set is
$$S=\bigcup_{N=1}^\infty S_N$$
Since a union of countable sets is countable, it suffices to show that each $S_N$ is countable. Now, argue by induction on $N$.

**ADDED (the induction argument):** $S_1$ is countable since its only element is the function $f(n)=1,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Now suppose $S_N$ is countable. A function in $S_{N+1}$ is either the constant function $f(n)=N+1,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, or it achieves some number $m=f(n_0)\leq N$ at some point $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$. Now after this $n_0$, the function can be considered as a function of $S_N$. Hence, to give a function in $S_{N+1}$ is to give an integer $n_0$ and a function in $S_{N}$. That is, $S_{N+1}$ is in bijection with $\mathbb{N}\times S_{N}$, which is countable since $S_N$ is countable (by the induction hypothesis). Hence, $S_{N+1}$ is countable.

Comment: I hadn't really thought of doing this way and i dont think i can do it but it looks a lot nicer, out of curiosity how do you show each SN is countable?

Comment: @user116498 I added the proof that each $S_N$ is countable.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:** Every [strictly] decreasing sequence of natural numbers is finite. Observe that a decreasing function is fully determined by a finite set of natural numbers, and conclude the countability.

Comment: Isn't that that same as my answer?

Comment: It's a different formulation of the hint which puts the emphasis on different parts of the hint. If you really want to start to quibble on "this answer is like that answer" I'm sure that we can find many examples on both of our accounts.

Comment: I asked because I am *genuinely* curious as to how you think it is different enough to warrant posting. I wondered if, based on your set-theoretic expertise, you might view it differently than do I and, as a result, see a much bigger difference than do I (to me it seems exactly the same). If so, I think it would be helpful to elaborate on that intuition, since many folks might learn from it (including I). When readers think my answer is a dup, often it turns out that I did not adequately explain some subtlety - one clear to me, but not to many readers. Maybe the same applies here.

Comment: You might be right. If that alright with you, please remind me to do that in a couple of days. As with most of my hints, I prefer to let the OP think about them - even if full answers were given.

Comment: I just saw your comment to dfeuer's answer, which seems to imply that one difference is that you think that the coding is simpler. I think it would be worth explicitly emphasizing that motivation, so that readers aren't left puzzled - as was I.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I have a doubt that two different decreasing functions can be represented by the same finite set of natural numbers so how would there be a bijection between the decreasing functions and the set of all finite subsets of natural numbers?

Comment: @Azminum: Can you see how a decreasing function can be represented uniquely by a finite set of ordered pairs of natural numbers?

Comment: Yes I see... we can just determine the natural number where the function steps down its current value and form ordered pairs ? this would be finite numbers of ordered pairs because every decreasing functions on $N$ is eventually a constant function. Yes but now confusing is that the ordered pairs are not equivalent to the sets containing the same element as the   ordered pairs as in set order of writing element doesn't matter.

Comment: @Azminum: Do you know that there is a bijection between $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb{N\times N}$?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ $ By *coding* a decreasing sequence by a *finite* sequence of naturals (e.g. list the *finite* number of places where it changes value) the set is a subset of $\,\bigcup_{\,k=1}^{\,\infty}\! \Bbb N^k,$ a countable union of countables.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; the number of  non-decreasing functions $f: \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$  is countable:
0)We know that these functions must be eventually constant, since f(1) is a finite value, and there are infinitely many values {$f(2),f(3),....$}. Say the functions is constant after $f(k)$.

1)Turn a function into a decimal string, by {$f(1),f(2),..,f(k),f(k),..$} $\rightarrow 0.f(1)f(2)....f(k)f(k)....$

2)Split the decimal image into the sum: $$0.f(1)f(2)...f(k-1)0000...0 +0.0000f(k)f(k)...f(k)...$$

3)Each of the terms of the sum is a Rational number, so the string represents a Rational number.

4)The collection then injects into the Rationals. But we know the set of  constant functions $f(n)=k; k=1,2,3,...$ is also non-decreasing. So the collection is countably-infinite.

---

Extended Explanation:
The set of non-decreasing functions is countable because every string $f(1),f(2),...,f(n)$ , when seen as a decimal expansion $0.f(1)f(2)....$, is a Rational  number. This is because the sequence {$f(1),f(2),...$} must be eventually-constant, i.e., there is an integer $k$ after which $f(k)=f(k+1)=....=f(k+n)=.....$.

So we have the assignment: $$ f(1),f(2),...,f(n),... \rightarrow 0.f(1)f(2)....f(n).. ..$$

And the claim is that the expression on the right, seen as a Real number, is Rational.

The proof of the claim is that , since the string is eventually-constant, say after the $k$-th spot, you can write the string as:

$\frac {.f(1).....f(k-1)}{10^{k-1}} + 0.00000000.f(k)f(k)....f(k)....=$ (where the first $f(k)$ starts at the $k-$th spot), which is a sum of Rationals, and it is then a Rational. So the (image) of the sequence of non-decreasing maps is a subset of the Rationals. EDIT: What we do is, if $f(k)$ has $n$ digits, we turn each digit into a term in the decimal expansion, e.g., if $f(x)=753$ , then $753 \rightarrow 0.00000753753...753....$

Note that the collections is infinite, since the constant sequence $f(n)=k; k=1,2,3,...$ does the job, i.e., it is non-decreasing.

Comment: How can you see such a string as a decimal expansion if it has numbers in it that are greater than $9$?

Comment: You're right; I should have been more clear: if the constant term has n digits, you set each of the digits as a term in the decimal expansion. Since n is finite, this can be done, so that, e.g., if $f(k)=753$ , then we use  $0.00000753753...753...$. I just edited it in.

Answer (score 0):

*Note for nerds: the following avoids the axiom of choice, but is not intuitionistically valid.*

Let $f\colon \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ be a decreasing function, where $\Bbb N = \{0,1,\dotsc\}$ (I am including $0$).

Let $n-1$ be the smallest number at which $f$ takes on its smallest value. Then we can represent $f$ as a *finite* sequence, an $n$-tuple, $f(0),f(1),\dotsc,f(n-1)$. The set of all such representations is then a subset of the set $\Bbb N^{<\omega}$ of tuples of natural numbers.

We want to show, then, that $T:=\Bbb N^{<\omega}$ is countable. Since a subset of a countable set is countable, this will prove the theorem.

*Note for nerds: what remains is entirely constructive, as far as I can see.*

There are many classic bijections from $\Bbb N\times \Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$. Pick your favorite and call it $p_2$. For each $n\ge 2$, let $p_{n+1}\colon \Bbb N^n\to n$ be defined by $p_{n+1}(x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n)=p_2(x_0,p_n(x_1,\dots,x_n))$. For completeness, let $p_1$ be the identity function on $\Bbb N$. By induction, you can easily see that $p_n$ is a bijection from $\Bbb N^n$ to $\Bbb N$ for each $n$.

Now that we have all these $p_n$s, let's put them together. For each tuple $(x_0,\dots,x_{n-1})$, let $q(x_0,\dots,x_{n-1})=p_2(n,p_n(x_0,\dots,x_{n-1}))$. That is, we're using $p_2$ to bundle up the length of the tuple with the result of applying $p_n$ to that tuple. But then $q$ is exactly what we're looking for: a bijection from $\Bbb N^{<\omega}$ to $\Bbb N$.

Comment: Note that while some of the proofs here may rely on the axiom of choice, we know that there is a uniform enumeration of the $\Bbb N^k$, and therefore their union is countable, without an appeal to the axiom of choice.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I am aware of that. My own proof is of essentially the same form and any of the others could be plugged into it. Aside from that, I think my proof is simpler than some, since it avoids worrying about where the function decreases (Bill Dubuque) or what its first value is (Spenser). Producing an injection to $\Bbb N^{<\omega}$ and proving the latter countable also produces a more modular proof. I'm not suggesting my way is the best, but explaining why I believe it adds something to the discussion.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I doubt this theorem holds constructively; do you have a sense of that?

Comment: My intuition about intuitionism sucks. I do know that the enumeration of $\omega^{<\omega}$ is recursive, so probably valid in all contexts, and that every decreasing sequence of natural numbers is finite seems also valid. I don't really know, sorry.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, my intuition about it stinks too. How would you show every decreasing sequence of naturals attains a minimum?

Comment: I don't really know. It just seems reasonable.